# How to locate config properties file when moving code to jenkins>

Tags: selenium, jenkins, webdriver

I am currently adding a config properties file to my test code. It works fine on my local machine but when I move it to Jenkins it fails. I think I know the problem but I am looking for the best solution. Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException{
     File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Test\\Regrassion_Framework\\src\\main\\java\\GUI\\config.properties");

        FileInputStream fileInput = null;
        try {
            fileInput = new FileInputStream(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Properties prop = new Properties();

        //load properties file
        try {
            prop.load(fileInput);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    System.err.println(prop.getProperty("url"));

}
```

}

I think the problem is that I specify my config file locally. Should I edit this when I move my code to jenkins and how? Should I do this manually or can this be done an easier way without the chance of human error causing propblems

Comment: The file location seems pretty hardcoded to me. Is the location on the jenkins machine the same? And maybe you can also post the stacktrace

Comment: I know its hard-coded. I'm asking for a way to to use the properties file without specifically hard-coding where it is on my machine and rather my project.

Comment: If it is a repository you check out, then it is pretty easy. I am no Java guru however. Maybe you can give a bit more detail on the folder structure and how you are running thisY, because it does not look like typical code you would want to run on a build server. You might want to checkout [filepath](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/FilePath.html) which can also handle remote slaves.

Answer (score 0):

If this properties file is only used with this one project, you can package it with your test code. You can load the resource like this:

```
InputStream is = YourTestClassName.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("your/package/name/testFiles/config.properties")
```

If it's used in multiple projects, consider putting it in a shared directory or storing it in source control.